# How to bind HTTP GET Request parameters to JavaBean object variables?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In this period I am studying the Sping MVC showcase example dowlodable form STS dashboard.

In the Request Data section is shown how to bind the parameter of an HTTP GET Request to the homonymous variables of a JavaBean.

In practice I have the following link:

```
 <a id="group" class="textLink" 
    href="<c:url value="/data/group?param1=foo&param2=bar&param3=baz" />">
       Group of query parameters
 </a>
```

This link generate a GET HTTP Request towards the "/data/group" URL. This request carries 3 parameter named param1, param2, param3.

This request is handled by the following method of my controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="group", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String withParamGroup(JavaBean bean) {
    return "Obtained parameter group " + bean;
}
```

The withParamGroup() method thake a JavaBean object that is only an object that contains 3 variables and getters/setters methods, something like this:

```
public class JavaBean {

    private String param1;
    private String param2;
    private String param3;

        // GETTER & SETTER method
}
```

So the param1 parameter in the HTTP Request is stored in the param1 variable of the JavaBean Object, and the same thing for param2 and param3.

Ok...I think that this is clear for me...but...who does this operation? Is it automatically made by Spring framework?

Why I have not to use something like @RequestParam annotation as I do when I bind a single HTTP Request parameter with a single variable in the controller method?

Another doubt is: the HTTP parameters names have to be the same of the JavaBean variables or simply the first parameter value is stored in the first variable of the JavaBean object?

Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly the Spring documentation appears to be somewhat short on details about this feature, but there are some points in the Spring MVC documentation which seems to indicate that Spring is responsible for applying this behavior during the request mapping process.  There is a reference to this ability in a section in the documentation on using the `@RequestParam` attribute to bind request parameters to method parameters (located [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-requestparam)):

> Type conversion is applied automatically if the target method parameter type is not String. See Section 16.3.3.14, “Method Parameters And Type Conversion”.

If you then go to the section referenced, the documentation suggests that primitive object types are converted automatically by Spring ([here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-typeconversion)):

> String-based values extracted from the request including request
>   parameters, path variables, request headers, and cookie values may
>   need to be converted to the target type of the method parameter or
>   field (e.g., binding a request parameter to a field in an
>   @ModelAttribute parameter) they're bound to. If the target type is not
>   String, Spring automatically converts to the appropriate type. All
>   simple types such as int, long, Date, etc. are supported. You can
>   further customize the conversion process through a WebDataBinder (see
>   Section 16.3.3.15, “Customizing WebDataBinder initialization”) or by
>   registering Formatters with the FormattingConversionService (see
>   Section 6.6, “Spring 3 Field Formatting”).

Unfortunately this does not seem to give an adequate explanation for why non-primitive object types are being converted, but perhaps the documentation is not current with the capabilities.

To your final point on whether or not the attribute names must match the parameters - this is conjecture as I cannot find any documentation to support it, but I would guess based on the behavior your are experiencing with this "feature" that Spring will look to match the parameters to attributes by name rather than order of parameters on the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RequestParam` annotation in controller with variable Name that uses in Get URL.

Comment: He says it is automatically done, without the need of the @RequestParam annotation, and he opened this question to ask why and by who...

Comment: So, for example, if in my JavaBean object I have 3 variables named: var1, var2, var3 I can do the following thing:

I pass the JavaBean ogject as input parameter to my controller method and I can use the @RequestParam to map the param1 HTTP Req parameter to var1, etcetc for every couple paramX\varX? Have I understand well?